# How to generate different random number for storage in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure but when i `print_r` the array, both random generated string are the same instead of different.

```
$amount_of_files = 2;
$generated_file_names = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $amount_of_files; $i++){
    $generated_file_names[] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
}
```

Comment: Given that this will probably execute several times per second, and the md5 requires a different value each time to generate a different hash, what would you expect if it looped several times with the same time() value?

Comment: See some examples here http://php.net/microtime

Comment: Thanks to other people who answered as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time()` returns it's value to the nearest second - your code is executing in much less time than that so the value is the same. If you want random values for each item in the array use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) or [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you, the mt_rand() works perfectly, both elements in the array are different. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<?php

$amount_of_files = 2;
$generated_file_names = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $amount_of_files; $i++){
    $generated_file_names[] = substr(md5(rand()),0,10);
}

print_r($generated_file_names);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `microtime()` php is looping soo fast 0 to 2 and `time()` is not changing so md5 is same and sub_str is same for all.